# indexPath Value of UICollectionView

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsindexpath, uicollectionview

When using a UICollectionView, I am perplexed with getting the `indexPath` value of the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` method.

I'm using the following line of code in the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` method:

```
//FileList is an NSArray of files from the Documents Folder within my app.
//This line gets the indexPath of the selected item and finds the same index in the Array
NSString *selectedItem = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[FileList objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]];

//Now the selected file name is displayed using NSLog
NSLog(@"Selected File: %@", selectedItem);
```

The problem is that the **indexPath always returns 0** (see below code) and as a result only the first item in the FileList NSArray is ever selected.

I've tried different parameters such as

- `indexPath.row`
- `indexPath.item`
- and just plain `indexPath`

ALL of these return a value of 0 in the following NSLog statement:

```
NSLog(@"index path: %d", indexPath.item); //I also tried indexPath.row here
```

Maybe I'm just formatting the NSString improperly, however I don't think this is the case as there are no warnings and I've tried formatting it differently in other places.

**Why does the indexPath always return 0?**

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Please show how you format the strings for `NSLog`

Comment: `.item` is the appropriate property here, but functionally this is no different to `.row`. You need to show more - how do you know it is zero? What is FileList?

Comment: I've edited the question and included how I format the string for NSLog and I've clarified what FileList is (please read commented code)

Comment: Your log probably isn't the problem, but it's overly complicated. Just do: NSLog(@"IndexPath: %d",indexPath.row);

Comment: I've simplified the log statement, however my question does not have to do with NSLog. I would like to know why the indexPath returns 0.

Comment: The question has been edited. Does anyone have any ideas on this?

Comment: Can you show the frame of the view and the collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath, i had same issue where i didn't edit the values to match the size of my custom cells.

Comment: This question had been solved. My question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608896/buttons-on-a-uicollectionviewcell describes the problem I was having. The comments on the accepted answer explain why that problem was occurring.

Comment: @RazorSharp be warned that the accepted answer to that question encourages REALLY bad design.

Answer (score 30):

At the risk of stating the obvious, make sure your code is in the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` method rather than `didDeselectItemAtIndexPath`. You will get very different `indexPath` values for a given touch event in the latter method and it's quite easy to insert the wrong one with Xcode's code completion.

Comment: Damn you, autocomplete

Comment: Let me add to the chorus of thanks.  That was driving me crazy, and my eyes passed right over the method name without ever really reading it.

Answer (score 1):

The delegate method you are using always provides the index path of the cell that was selected.
Try to debug with a breakpoint on your NSLog call. When debugger stops on it look at the Debug Area at the bottom and use the console (View => Debug Area => Activate Console if you need it).

Type in the console: `po indexPath`

You should see something like this if selected item is the 5th of the list in section:0 (first section and probably the only one)

`<NSIndexPath 0xa8a6050> 2 indexes [0, 5]`

Hope this helps to figure out what's going on.